# Group count Aggeration in Springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation( 
other operations ////
Aggregation.group("name") .first("$$ROOT").as("doc").count().as("Total"), 
other operations ////
);
```

Here we store the count the value of group operation and store in String variable "Total", How can we get the value of count in int format?

Note: I use Mongo Template.

Comment: How are you working with the `Total` value after grouping documents? The `group` operator returns the numeric value of count because `count()` method generates `$sum: 1` in the query. So the `Total` cannot be a string.
And show us the calling of `mongoTemplate.aggregate`. What class do you use for the output?

Comment: Oh, I am not sure about it. I need to get the total size(count) of the group operation. I use Pojo class. MongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, class<>,class<>).getMappedResults();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count documents belonged to each group, you should use the following code snippet:

```
public class GroupCount {
    public String name;
    public YourDocument doc;
    public Long count;
}

...

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation( 
    // some aggregation operations
    Aggregation.group("name")
        .first("$$ROOT").as("doc")
        .count().as("total")
); 
AggregationResults<GroupCount> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
        aggregation, YourDocument.class, GroupCount.class);
List<GroupCount> groupCounts = results.getMappedResults();
```

`YourDocument` is a class that describes documents you group. `GroupCount` is a class that represents the result of the aggregation (I suggested the `name` field is a string).

You prepare your aggregation pipeline and call the `aggregate` method. It returns aggregation results described as `GroupCount` objects. And then you can get count of each group by calling `getMappedResults`.

If you do something else after grouping documents, the result may be other that `GroupCount`, and you have to consider it and change the class that describes the result of the aggregation.